# Saving empty embedded map into a document

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am a beginner in mongo db and for my application i am trying to save a mongo doc with one empty map(which is defined as an embedded object). So after the save I want to see it like: `myMap {}`
The problem is after the save happens the saved doc doesn't have the field myMap at all(other fields are populated correctly).We are using the BasicDAO class to call the save method on the object. 
Can someone please help with this?

Thanks in advance!